# OpenCV compile Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv, init, qmake

i have succesfully installed OpenCv & Qt in Ubuntu..i can debug and run some sample codes but when i create QtConsole Application i cant build it...
here is my sample code to randomly white some pixels in image

```
opencv2/core/core.hpp
opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp
void salt(cv::Mat &image, int n)
{
    for(int k=0; k<n; k++)
    {
        int i=rand()%image.cols;
        int j=rand()%image.rows;

        if(image.channels() == 1)
        {
            image.at<uchar>(j,i)=255;
        }
        else if(image.channels() == 3)
        {
            image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0]=255;
            image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[1]=255;
            image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[2]=255;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    cv::Mat resim = cv::imread("boldt.jpg");
    salt(resim,3000);
    cv::namedWindow("Cerceve");
    cv::imshow("Cerceve",resim);
}
```

I have added my libraires in `.pro` file like

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv2

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d
```

when I try to run program from Terminal
it says :

> init done
>
> opengl support available

and nothing happens..
there is no error while debugging

Comment: Edited tags as I can see nothing which indicates use of the Qt libraries. You're just using qmake as your makefile maker. For reference, a Qt console application has a main which looks like `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { QCoreApplication a(argc, argv); return a.exec(); }`

Comment: Have you been able to build and successfully run a non-Qt application that uses the OpenCV binary you built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `cv::waitKey(..)` at the end of main()

```
cv::imshow("Cerceve",resim);
cv::waitKey(0);
return 0;
```

Calling `cv::waitKey(param)` is crucial because it is what processes the event loop in the window you have opened (apart from returning the key the user pressed during the wait time). Here `param` is the number of milliseconds to wait before the function returns. Use `0` for infinite wait till some key is pressed.

Comment: I am still getting output as init done opengl support available while my actual program runs prerfectly.
Plz help.

Comment: I have asked it as a new question but no one has replied. The link to the question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509058/why-am-i-getting-init-done-opengl-support-available-output-even-when-i-am-not
Please help.